# apache-maven-3.6.0.zip: Permission denied

Tags: software-installation

while running the below command i am facing this error

```
wget http://us.mirrors.quenda.co/apache/maven/maven-3/3.6.0/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.0-bin.zip -O apache-maven-3.6.0.zip
apache-maven-3.6.0.zip: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are in a directory not writable to your current user.

Try this instead. You will find the application downloaded and saved to your desktop.

```
cd ~/Desktop/
wget http://us.mirrors.quenda.co/apache/maven/maven-3/3.6.0/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.0-bin.zip -O apache-maven-3.6.0.zip
```

#### Example:

In my home directory, download is successful:

```
subroot@subroot:~$ wget http://us.mirrors.quenda.co/apache/maven/maven-3/3.6.0/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.0-bin.zip -O apache-maven-3.6.0.zip
--2019-05-15 11:06:47--  http://us.mirrors.quenda.co/apache/maven/maven-3/3.6.0/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.0-bin.zip
Resolving us.mirrors.quenda.co (us.mirrors.quenda.co)... 108.61.245.101, 2001:19f0:a:5::28a6
Connecting to us.mirrors.quenda.co (us.mirrors.quenda.co)|108.61.245.101|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 9102386 (8.7M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘apache-maven-3.6.0.zip’

apache-maven-3.6.0.zip                   100%[================================================================================>]   8.68M  1.59MB/s    in 13s     

2019-05-15 11:07:01 (700 KB/s) - ‘apache-maven-3.6.0.zip’ saved [9102386/9102386]

subroot@subroot:~$
```

But if I change to the root folder `/` I can't download because I don't have permission to write to that folder.

```
subroot@subroot:~$ cd /
subroot@subroot:/$ wget http://us.mirrors.quenda.co/apache/maven/maven-3/3.6.0/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.0-bin.zip -O apache-maven-3.6.0.zip
apache-maven-3.6.0.zip: Permission denied
subroot@subroot:/$
```

Comment: Now it's working fine

Comment: @vidyadhar Cool. Kindly accept the answer to mark this question as resolved.